# Before/after delete trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following trigger in my DB table:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER `ordernumberdelete` AFTER DELETE ON `classes`
  FOR EACH ROW UPDATE classes set ordernumber = ordernumber-1 where ordernumber>old.ordernumber
```

which basically drops a value in an ordernumber column by one if it is higher than the deleted row's order number - plain and simple.

The call to delete the row is using PHP/ajax/mysqli prepared statements but I am getting the error:

can't update table 'classes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invokes this stored function/trigger in ....

Looked all over SO/Google and can't see a solution. I though the trigger was done after the mysqli_stmt_execute call.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if changing the order number is a good idea though.  Why do you need to?

Comment: Just so you get a maintained 1,2,3,...10 etc instead of a 3,6,9,23,667,3332 pattern as data is added/removed.